# How to check if drive with certain label exists in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have this drive: `KTEST(K:)` - drive `K` labeled `KTEST`. I need to find out if a drive with label `KTEST`, be it `A:` or `K:` or `J:` exists. In my case it exists as `KTEST(K:)`, but if it say doesn't, how can I do that?

Sorry if repeated, couldn't really find out.

One of tried ones:

`if exists KTEST:\ @echo exists`

...and many more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a WMI query.

```js
wmic logicaldisk where "VolumeName='KTEST'" get Name /value
```

Full example:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%I in (
    '2^>NUL wmic logicaldisk where "VolumeName='KTEST'" get Name /value ^| find "="'
) do set "%%I"

if defined Name echo It exists!
```

Or with [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution):

```js
@echo off
setlocal

2>NUL wmic logicaldisk where "VolumeName='KTEST'" get Name /value | find "=" >NUL && (
    echo It exists!
) || (
    echo It doesn't exist.
)
```

Comment: Don't you need `"tokens=2 delims=="` for `for /F`?

Comment: @aschipfl Nnnnope.  I leave the explanation why not as an exercise for the reader.  :)

Comment: Ah, got it, very clever, +1!

Comment: According to [this question on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/q/1074840), it would be better to use `DeviceID` rather than `Name`...

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=6*" %A in ('dir c:\zzzz ^| Findstr /c:"Volume in drive"') do echo %A
```

Use `%%A` in batch. See `for /?`, `dir /?`, and `findstr /?`.

Comment: Good idea, but you are only checking the label of `C:`, which does not cover the whole question...